# Thread not starting

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to run a clock on the console application of C#. It should be pretty straight forward s=using threads and stopwatch, but somehow i cant start the thread.. here's the code:

```
public static void showBoard()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i< 40 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ;j<40 ; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(board[i, j]);
        }
        Console.Write('\n');
    }
    Thread t = new Thread(Timer);
}

public static void Timer()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(45, 1);
        Console.Write(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
}
```

Function Timer dont even start the excution, kindly tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You need to read description of class you are using on MSDN before asking question. [MSDN Thread class description which even have sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

Comment: yea i'm well aware of that, but as my reputation score is low so i need to wait for some time before i can accept any answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you forgot something

```
t.Start();
```

Threads need to be started explicitly, otherwise they don't run.

Answer (score 6):

You need to start it with

```
t.Start();
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly start a thread. 
Use `t.Start() ;`
or
Do this

```
    Thread t = new Thread(Timer).Start() ;
```

Check the following links if you need further info:-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6678/Introduction-to-Threads-in-C
http://www.albahari.info/threading/threading.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You need to add...

```
t.Start
```

...to start your thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have created object of thread class, and now you have to start the thread, which you can do use the `Start()` method.

```
 Thread t = new Thread(Timer);
 t.Start();
```